# Access synology shared folder from PHP

Tags: php, synology

I am hosting a web station from my Synology NAS, this creates a folder under - `/volume1/web/website`. However, i wish to access another shared folder `volume1/shared/` from my web page. This shared folder requires authentication which I can access however I am unsure about getting access using a PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. There is some feedback around, and this article looks like it has an answer: http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Zina_Media_Server

Essentially you need to edit the `open_basedir` configuration in `php.ini` to allow PHP to access these folders. Out of the box PHP is locked out of shares.

Further to this, new versions of DSM (5+) provide handy access to the `open_basedir` directive from within the control panel. Tested and successful!

[image: Custom open_basedir in DSM 5]

Comment: That link is no longer active. I was able to check the open_basedir but I'm still not sure how to actually access the files in my PHP script.