# Synology - access from web directory to other directory

Tags: php, html, apache, synology

I have Synology DS1515+ and I've installed Web Station with Apache and PHP on it. I have web directory (full path /volume1/web) in which I can host webpages.
I have PHP file with tag video in which I would like to have video from video directory (full path /volume1/video). 
So in web directory in PHP file I have something like below, but video file isn't hosted:

```
<video id="video" autoplay>
    <source src="/volume1/video/movie.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

I also tried related path like '../video/movie.mp4' but it also doesn't work.
I read this question: [Access synology shared folder from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267971/access-synology-shared-folder-from-php) and I edited open_basedir but it took no effect.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your src needs to be relevant to the apache path being served.

E.g. if apache is serving content from /volume1/website/public_html your source is relative to this folder. You won't be able to break out of this to get to /volume1/video/movie.mp4 either.

Try looking at apache getting started here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/getting-started.html

Comment: Ok, but I wrote that relevant path doesn't work either :(
I tried "../../video.movie.mp4".

Comment: As mentioned apache wont let you out of the directory its serving from. For example if apache is serving this directory `/volume1/website/public_html` then you cannot escape out of this directory with `../`. By doing `../../video.movie.mp4` as you are at the top level its looking for the file at `/volume1/website/public_html/video.movie.mp4`. To verify this is the case simply copy your `video.movie.mp4` to your apache served directory and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Some will no doubt go on to voice their concerns - and normally I'd say rightly so.

However, goto Web Station, click on PHP Settings, select PHP version and add /volume1/video/ to the end of open_basedir, i.e. add :/volume1/video/ paths are split by a :

I do similar to serve photo's from outside the web root. I then have a PHP script to fetch the file required from /volume1/photo (in my case). and use like src="getfile.php?name=file.jpg" which can access the file you want and provide it. Bit of a workaround but it works.

Comment: I did this but it's giving me a permission denied in my PHP, any ideas? I was able to get it to scandir() volume1 when I'm in volume2 but when I go further into volume1 it gives the permission error.

Comment: Make sure its the correct ini file... I think its uses a different one for CLI vs web, if using  command line: php -info | grep ini and check what ini file its using and if its web see what ini file is reported using phpinfo()

Similarly from cli, php -info | grep open_basedir will show if its set, or via web check what open_basedir has set.

Also, apache/needs restarted after editing, the GUI should do so.

You can always edit the ini file manually and restart manually (or even reboot NAS) to make sure.